# How to use pessimistic locking in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to do pessimistic locking in laravel framework. For that i have passed the `id` of the row with ajax to my controller. And my controller look like this.

```
public function edit(){                                       
   DB::table('tbl_plants')->where('id',request('id'))->lockForUpdate()->get();
}
```

After that i'm trying to edit the row with different browsers at the same time. But it's not working. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: what you expect from `lockForUpdate` ? how long it keeps locked  ?

Comment: @user2486 I need to lock it around 1min. From `lockForUpdate` i expect to prevent changes form other users when one user editing the record.